# Construct a connected compact set but nowhere locally connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Can we construct a connected compact set $X$ in $\mathbb{C}$ ,s.t. it is not locally connected at any point in $X$？

My idea: I know that the topologist's sine curve is connected compact, and also not locally connected at some points, but not all. I cannot find other examples.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The [pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) and the [Brouwer–Janiszewski–Knaster continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum) (buckethandle) both work.

This kind of question falls within the realm of "continuum theory" which dives deep into these kinds of topological phenomena.

Comment: Another example in the same spirit is the [Smale-Williams attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)). Wikipedia has a nice [animation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solenoid.gif#/media/File:Solenoid.gif) of its construction.

Comment: More generally, any indecomposable continuum has the desired properties, so searching on *indecomposable continuum* is likely to be useful.