# Is the pseudoarc nowhere locally connected on any subspace which does not contain isolated points?

Tags: general-topology, continuum-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be the [pseudoarc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc), which is a [hereditarily indecomposable continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum). Here hereditary means on every subcontinuum. Subcontinuums of a continuum are exactly its closed and connected subsets.

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4747668/51161) it was established that any indecomposable continuum is nowhere locally connected. Hence the pseudoarc is nowhere locally connected on any closed and connected subspace.

Suppose $U \subset X$ is non-empty and $(U, \mathcal{T}|U)$ does not contain isolated points.

Is $(U, \mathcal{T}|U)$ nowhere locally connected?

Comment: Hi, unrelated to your question here, but you will probably find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760309 interesting, as you have edited wikipedia regarding this notion.

Comment: Pick a point $x$, then take a composant $K_0$ of $X$ containing $x$.  By Kuratowski, $K_1 = \cup P_{1, n}$ an increasing union of subcontinua of $X$ containing $x$ and converging to $X$ - aka union of pseudo-arcs.  Take a composant $K_1$ of $P_{1, 1}$, repeat, taking composants $K_n$ of $P_{n,n}$.  We may assume by taking sufficient indices that the Hausdorff distance $d_H(X, \lim P_{n,n}) > 0$ by density.  Then $P = \cap P_{n,n}$ is not a point.  By a standard result it's a continuum, aka the pseudo-arc again, not lc.  This is how one must try to build a counterexample, but it fails.

Comment: @JohnSamples I have trouble understanding what you are saying here. Are you saying that a counterexample, if it exists, must be of this form? Or that you think this`kind of approach could give an counterexample but this particular example didn't?

Comment: @kaba Any such counterexample must be constructed roughly in this manner (rigorous proof will be a bit messier, taking sub-pseudo-arcs in nbhds), it's just a proof sketch.  This is a well-known fact but I don't know a reference for it.

Comment: Oh sorry, rather I should say $\lim d_H(X, P_{n,n}) < \epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon$ by taking sufficient indices in the second coordinate.  Just being fussy in saying you can construct them so that their intersection isn't a point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer which provides an affirmitive answer for the non-empty locally closed subsets without isolated points.

- If $U \in \mathcal{T} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, then $\mathcal{T}|U$ is nowhere locally connected. For otherwise $\mathcal{T}$ would be not be nowhere locally connected.
- The following shows a that each non-empty closed subset which does not contain a singleton component is nowhere locally connected. For let $V \subset X$ be such. Then the connected components of $V$ are closed, connected, and non-degenerate, hence pseudoarcs. Now let $x \in V$ and $U \in (\mathcal{T}|V)(x)$ be connected. By connectedness, $U$ must be contained in some component of $C$. Hence $V$ is not locally connected at $x$.
- The following extends the previous to show that any non-empty closed subset without isolated points is nowhere locally connected. For if some component of $V$ is a singleton $\{x\}$, then there is no connected open subset which contains $x$, since that would imply that $\{x\}$ is open and hence isolated.
- A corollary is that any non-empty locally closed subset without isolated points is nowhere locally connected. Here locally closed means an intersection of an open set and a closed set.